# Make median and quartile split columns of data in data frame, based on condition (R)

Tags: r, split, grouping, median, quartile

If I use mtcars as an example:

```
 mtcars <- subset(mtcars, select = c("cyl", "disp"))
```

How can I add two additional columns, one that indicates that values are below/above the median and one that indicates which quartile the values are in? However, I would like this to be done per group of `cyl`.

This is the specific outcome I am hoping for:

```
                   cyl  disp    median_split    quartile_split
 Toyota Corolla    4    71.1    below_median    1st_quartile
 Honda Civic       4    75.7    below_median    1st_quartile
 Fiat 128          4    78.7    below_median    1st_quartile
 Fiat X1-9         4    79      below_median    2nd_quartile
 Lotus Europa      4    95.1    below_median    2nd_quartile
 Datsun 710        4    108     median          median
 Toyota Corona     4    120.1   above_median    3rd_quartile
 Porsche 914-2     4    120.3   above_median    3rd_quartile
 Volvo 142E        4    121     above_median    4th_quartile
 Merc 230          4    140.8   above_median    4th_quartile
 Merc 240D         4    146.7   above_median    4th_quartile
 Ferrari Dino      6    145     below_median    1st_quartile
 Mazda RX4         6    160     etc…            etc…
```

I would appreciate help. Thank you.

**Edit following on from akun's answer below**

In the `quartile_split` column, akun's answer left the lowest value in each cyl group with `NA`. I thought I could fix this by adding:

```
 mtcars$quartile_split[is.na(mtcars$quartile_split)] <- "1_quartile" #not a very elegant solution
```

So the full code would be:

```
 library(dplyr)
 mtcars <- subset(mtcars, select = c("cyl", "disp"))
 # akrun's answer
 mtcars <- mtcars %>%
     group_by(cyl) %>% 
     mutate(median_split = c("above_median", "below_median")[1 + 
                   (disp <= median(disp))], 
            quartile_split = cut(disp, breaks = quantile(disp), 
                 labels = paste0(1:4, "_quartile")))
 # addition
 mtcars$quartile_split[is.na(mtcars$quartile_split)] <- "1_quartile" #not a very elegant solution
```

However, when I looked more carefully, I also found something else that did not seem quite right, specifically, when you look at the `cyl = 6` group only, you see this:

```
 cyl  disp      median_split    quartile_split
 6    145       below_median    1_quartile
 6    160       below_median    1_quartile
 6    160       below_median    1_quartile
 6    167.6     below_median    2_quartile
 6    167.6     below_median    2_quartile
 6    225       above_median    4_quartile
 6    258       above_median    4_quartile
```

The median `disp` in this group is 163.8, so the two cars with `disp = 167.6` should be classified as "above_median", instead of "below_median".

I hope this could be solved, somehow. Thank you again.

Comment: You can create a new column in the data.frame by assigning a value to it:
`mtcars$median_split <- #some expression`
will crate the column and assign the result of the expression to it for each row.

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to group by 'cyl', use `cut` to create the different categories based on the `quantile` on 'disp' column

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    mutate(median_split = c("above_median", "below_median")[1 + 
                  (disp <= median(disp))], 
           quartile_split = cut(disp, breaks = quantile(disp), 
                labels = paste0(1:4, "_quartile")))
```

Comment: Thank you, akrun. This is great, but the only point is that, as per @BigBowlOfXoop 's answer below, the lowest value in each `cyl` group is labelled `NA`.

Comment: Please see the edit of my question above for my further comments. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

With base R and `cut`:

```
mtcars <- subset(mtcars, select = c("cyl", "disp"))
mtcars$median_split <- ifelse(mtcars$disp <= median(mtcars$disp), "below_median","above_median")
mtcars$quantile_split <- cut(mtcars$disp, breaks = c(0, quantile(mtcars$disp)),labels = c("1_quartile",paste0(1:4, "_quartile")))
```

Be careful when using the `cut` function to make sure the breaks include the minimum (or it will return NA), and that the min. is labelled in the 1st quartile.

Comment: Thank you, BigBowlOfXoop. You are right about @akrun 's answer. However, it looks like you are missing the `group by` component, because the median/quartile splits are applied to the whole dataset, rather than per `cyl` group. Thank you, though. I'll try to distill a combination from both your answers.

Comment: Oh sorry about that @SylviaRodriguez I didn't notice the group by cyl !